# What is the easiest way to remove the Silverlight TextBox mouse hover border?

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, textblock, cut-and-paste

I want to display text in a **Silverlight** application so that the user can **copy and paste** it elsewhere (as one is used to doing on an **HTML** web site).

If I use **TextBlock**, then the user cannot copy and paste.

Therefore I use **TextBox**, but it has a **default border** on it. I can **remove** the border with `BorderThickness="0"` like this:

```
<TextBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Text="{Binding ViewModelBindingStringsBlockHelp}"/>
```

which works great:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/45p34i.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/45p34i.png)

However, when the user **hovers** over the text box to select the text, **another border appears**:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1k7m44p.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1k7m44p.png)

I've found [purported solutions](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/41148/116561.aspx) for removing this border but they unbelievably seem to require **pages** of XAML.

I'm looking for a **simple solution** like this:

```
HoverBorderThickness="0"
```

**What is an easy way to hide the hover border on a Silverlight TextBox?**

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you've encountered wanting to do something that compositely seems relatively simple, but you have to jump through a few hoops to do it. As forementioned in the previous answers, you **will** need to restyle / retemplate the textbox as it is.

As for the hover state - this is a relatively large point of Silverlight that you should get to grips with - it's the idea that every control has separate *states*.

Expression Blend is an excellent way to deal with these states - you can easily see what the in-build XAML templates and styles are and edit them on-the-fly with minimal effort. Can be tricky at times, and it sure-as-hell makes your XAML a little bulky, but that's the cost you have for making a control **do exactly what you want it to do, when you want it to.**

Harness the power of states - especially within Blend - and I guarantee you'll realise how much easier your life can be made.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for creating readonly textbox without background and borders:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private String readOnlyText;
    public String ReadOnlyText
    {
        get
        {
            return readOnlyText;
        }
        set
        {
            readOnlyText = value;
            this.Text = readOnlyText;
        }
    }

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        this.TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap;
        this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(MyTextBox_GotFocus);
        this.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(MyTextBox_MouseEnter);
        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MyTextBox_MouseMove);
        this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(MyTextBox_TextChanged);
    }

    void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ReadOnlyText))
        {
            var lS = this.SelectionStart; var lL = this.SelectionLength;
            this.Text = this.ReadOnlyText;
            this.SelectionStart = lS; this.SelectionLength = lL;
        }
    }

    void MyTextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
    }

    void MyTextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
    }

    void MyTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you do need to re-template. Using Blend will make this easier than hand-editing.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply this style to your textbox. This is the only way you can do it.

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
     <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
     </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
      <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
         <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
         <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">

         </VisualState>
         <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
          <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
          </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>
         <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
          <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement"/>
          </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
         <VisualState x:Name="Focused">          
         </VisualState>
         <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
         </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
         <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
         <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
          <Storyboard>
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
             </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>
         <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
          <Storyboard>
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
             </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
              <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
             </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid>
         <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="#5EC9C9C9" Opacity="0"/>
         <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
         </Border>
        </Grid>

       <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#A5F7F7F7" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>       
       <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
          <ToolTip.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
             <Storyboard>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                 <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
               </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
           </EventTrigger>
          </ToolTip.Triggers>
         </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
         <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
         <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
       </Border>
      </Grid>
     </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the property `Readonly` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing there is the Focus element.  It's part of the default template for textboxes.  Making your own template is the best way to get control of your element's style.  Just remove the main border and the border of the focus element, and you should be good to go. Then you won't need to set the border thickness inline in your XAML anymore either.